# When deleting an exoplayer download DownloadTracker.isDownloaded() returns true

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, download-manager

I am having trouble determining wether a download is still downloaded if the download's files were removed from storage through the file explorer.

I used the [example code](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/demos/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/demo) provided by the exoplayer team to implement my downloader.

I have a function that executes when the app returns to focus that loops through all the known downloads and uses the `isDownloaded()` function to determine whether each of the downloads is still downloaded. But when I delete all the files created by the download-manager in the file manager and I switch back to the app the function still returns true. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
for (int i=0; I<downloadIDs.size(); i++) {
    String stringUri = getUri(downloadIDs.get(i));
    if (stringUri != null) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(stringUri);
        if (downloadTracker.isDownloaded(uri)) {
            isDownloadedDownloadIDs.add(downloadIDs.getString(i));
        }
    }
}
```

The downloadID still gets added to the isDownloadedDownloadIDs ArrayList even though the files have been deleted.

Edit: Added java tag